# How to bind data based on web part added in section?

Tags: css, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepointframework

I have created a SharePoint Framework web part.

I have dynamically bound boxes under that web part.

I have added that web part to SharePoint modern page one-third right section.

Below is the screenshot of the page section layout.
[image]

I need to bind boxes based on the web part added in the section,

1. If the web part is added in the left side (more width) section. Boxes should bind in a below manner,
   [image]
2. If the web part is added in the right side (less width) section. Boxes should bind in a below manner,
   [image]

In short, if the section is big boxes bind in 3 column layout, and if the section is small boxes bind in 2 column layout.

Can anyone help me with the same?